# How to create a dbcontext with code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-first, dbcontext

I'm a beginner in programming and right now I'm trying to build a web application in ASP.Net. The problem I have right is how to create a DBContext with Code first.
This is my models:

```
public class Messages {
        public int MessageID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(300, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string MessageContent { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Sender { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Receiver { get; set; }
    }


    public class FriendRequest {
        public int RequestId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser RequestFrom { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser RequestTo { get; set; }
        public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
    }


public class DejtingsidaDbContext : DbContext {

        public DejtingsidaDbContext() : base() { }

        public virtual DbSet<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FriendRequest> Requests { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the HomeController:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        DejtingsidaDbContext db = new DejtingsidaDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About() {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact() {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();

        }
    }
```

I've tried to create a connection string in the Web.config, but when I first run the program and then when I check if the database has been created, it has not been created. Please help a beginner out!

Comment: Perhaps this article will help you (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database)

Comment: Check for newly created database by connecting to SQLExpress. Also, if you want to use connectionstring in web.config, you need to pass it to `base` constructor in `DejtingsidaDbContext ` class

Answer (score 0):

pass connection string in web.cofig file like shown below.

```
<connectionStrings>  
<add name="yourconnectinstringName" 
connectionString="
Data Source= DatabaseServerName(example:uzainPC);
Integrated Security=true;
Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName(example:SchoolSystem); 
uid=YourUserName; 
Password=yourpassword; " 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>   
</connectionStrings>
```

than remove virtual from these lines shown below.

```
public class DejtingsidaDbContext : DbContext {
public DejtingsidaDbContext() : base() { }

public DbSet<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
public DbSet<FriendRequest> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would dbContext know that it has to use the connectionstring from web.config?